# User in Domain or Outside Domain

Tags: vb.net, wcf, http

I have the following requirement. I have many users log into my system either from within my domain (intranet and on the VPN) or from outside the domain from public internet. I would like to know from where users log in and route them separately. (bind them to specific endpoints on a WCF service) 
I tried using the "Environment" variable. But there is one special case that I would like to address. People who have a laptop that is registered in the domain always show as "Being in Domain" even when logging in from an outside network. How do I go about solving this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can reliably do this. I think the best course of action would be to have an internal server and an external server (or at least two separate applications, one accessible from the local intranet and one accessible from the internet. When accessing the application internally the companies internal DNS would route to the internal version of the application. And externally would route to the external version of the application.

There are similar questions here,

[How to detect if machine is joined to domain (in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926227/how-to-detect-if-machine-is-joined-to-domain-in-c)

and here

[Detecting a users domain in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264699/detecting-a-users-domain-in-asp-net)